# SSH help for name resolution error

Tags: ssh, putty

I'm trying to ssh to a domain as shown below and keep getting the name resolution failure. I've gotten same error on Kali Linux and 2 other computers. I also re-installed putty but to no avail. Anything I'm missing?

[image]

Comment: This is part of the https://overthewire.org/wargames/ - those tasks are supposed to be riddles and you probably won't get an answer here, as the solution is likely not standard.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Using "level_name@localhost" works. 
Example: ssh bandit5@localhost. Dunno why, but it the only solution I could find.

Answer (score 0):

I would check your DNS settings and be sure you're using a DNS server that knows about bandit.labs.overthewire.org.

try pinging that address, to see if an IP returns.

try ssh into the host by IP address instead.

Comment: Tried that and got the same error. I tried on a different computer on a completely different Network and another computer on the same network and keep getting the same error. From my understanding, that rules out a dns server error.

Comment: Can you use nslookup to see if bandit.labs.overthewire.org returns an IP?